# should friend functions be represented in UML diagrams?

Tags: c++, uml

Also, how exactly are overloaded operator member functions best formatted in a UML diagram?

Here is my class:

```
class matrix
{
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const matrix&);
    friend bool operator == (const matrix &, const matrix &);
    friend matrix operator - (const matrix &, const matrix &);

    private:
    int size;
    int range;
    int array[10][10];

    public:
    matrix(int);
    matrix(int, int);
    bool operator != (const matrix &) const;
    matrix operator + (const matrix &) const;
    const matrix & operator = (const matrix &);
};
```

and here is what I have of my UML diagram so far:

[image]

Comment: Just a word of advice, do your UML diagrams with StavrUML/StarUML instead of using a word processor, it's much easier :) http://sourceforge.net/projects/stavruml/

Answer (score 3):

By placing the stereotype `<<friend>>` in front of the operation in the UML class diagram.
You will have to do it this way:

```
<<friend>> ostream& operator << (ostream&, const matrix&)
<<friend>> bool operator == (const matrix &, const matrix &)
<<friend>> matrix operator - (const matrix &, const matrix &)
```

Comment: What would be an example of a stereotype friend; an italian pasta-lover? :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: :) No worries, probably I don't have good sense of humor :)